# Angular 2 template parsing error when test is running

Tags: angular, testing, typescript, karma-runner

So I have a simple component:

galery.comonent.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'galery-component',
  templateUrl: 'galery.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['galery.component.css']
})
export class GaleryComponent {
  @Input() userPosts;
}
```

With a custom tag in it's html file.This tag is a selector of another component of my module.

galery.comonent.html

```
 <div class="container">
        <post-details class="post-container" *ngFor="let post of userPosts" [singlePost] = "post">
        </post-details>
    </div>
```

When I try to run my test case It fails on start with this error

> 1. If 'post-details' is an Angular component and it has 'singlePost' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'post-details' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>      to suppress this message.

Here is a test code:

test.spec.ts

```
describe('BannerComponent (inline template)', () => {

  let comp:    GaleryComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<GaleryComponent>;
  let de:      DebugElement;
  let el:      HTMLElement;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ GaleryComponent ],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GaleryComponent); // here test fails

    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('post-details'));
    el = de.nativeElement;
  });
```

I've added a CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to my module but nothing works.
Here is app.module.ts

app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {GaleryComponent} from './Components/galeryComponent/galery.component';
import {PostDetailsComponent} from './Components/postDetailsComponent/post-details-component.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GaleryComponent,
    PostDetailsComponent
  ],
  exports: [GaleryComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

Maybe someone knows what happened? I've read some answers to similar questions but they were not very helpful.

Comment: Your testing module only declares GaleryComponent. But GaleryComponent needs PostDetailsComponent to work (since it uses it in its template). So you need to declare it, too. CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA is irrelevant: PostDetailsComponent is an angular component, not a Web Component. The error message tells you what to do: *If 'post-details' is an Angular component [it is], then verify that it is part of this module*.

Comment: ^^ i.e. include it in the `declarations` in the `TestBed` config

Comment: I've tried to declare PostDetailsComponent in test.ts but there is still an error.

Comment: Again, it's useful to read the error message. Telling us "there is an error" doesn't help at all.

Comment: I meant that error is the same. But everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you defined schema in wrong place

Try

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [GaleryComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] // will work if selector has '-' in its name
})
```

or

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [GaleryComponent],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
```

See also

- [Essential Angular: Testing](https://blog.nrwl.io/essential-angular-testing-192315f8be9b#.s8uyufp7u)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the property binding `[singlePost]` and it try to find it in the @Input.

Make sure your property binding is proper.